# why does BluetoothSetLocalServiceInfo throw error 1314?

Tags: c++, windows, bluetooth

I have being trying to build a BT application. I would like to use BluetoothSetLocalServiceInfo but I get an error 1314 (A required privilege is not held by the client).
I use the echo bluetooth example from windows driver. That's my modified code:

```
DEFINE_GUID(BTHECHOSAMPLE_SVC_GUID, 0xc07508f2, 0xb970, 0x43ca, 0xb5, 0xdd, 0xcc, 0x4f, 0x23, 0x91, 0xbe, 0xf4);
wchar_t name[17] = L"BthEchoSampleSrv";
extern __declspec(selectany) const PWSTR BthEchoSampleSvcName = name;
/* fc71b33d-d528-4763-a86c-78777c7bcd7b */
DEFINE_GUID(BTHECHOSAMPLE_DEVICE_INTERFACE, 0xfc71b33d, 0xd528, 0x4763, 0xa8, 0x6c, 0x78, 0x77, 0x7c, 0x7b, 0xcd, 0x7b);

int main(){

  DWORD err = ERROR_SUCCESS;
  BLUETOOTH_LOCAL_SERVICE_INFO SvcInfo = { 0 };
  SvcInfo.Enabled = true;

  if (FAILED(StringCbCopyW(SvcInfo.szName, sizeof(SvcInfo.szName), BthEchoSampleSvcName)))
  {
    printf("Copying svc name failed\n");
    goto exit;
  }

  std::cout<<"Name of the device: "<< SvcInfo.szName<<std::endl;

  if (ERROR_SUCCESS != (err = BluetoothSetLocalServiceInfo(
    NULL, //callee would select the first found radio
    &BTHECHOSAMPLE_SVC_GUID,
    0,
    &SvcInfo
  )))
  {
    printf("BluetoothSetLocalServiceInfo failed, err = %d\n", err);
    goto exit;
  }
exit:
  return err;
}
```

I run the code in a commandline (opened as admin) and I changed properties of the app to be run with admin previlages. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error 1314 is `ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD`. Per the [`BluetoothSetLocalServiceInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothsetlocalserviceinfo) documentation:

> The `BluetoothSetLocalServiceInfo` function returns the following values:
>
> ...
>
> STATUS_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD
> The caller does not have the required privileges. See the Remarks section for information about how to elevate privileges.

And the Remarks say:

> Warning
> **The process that calls `BluetoothSetLocalServiceInfo` must have the `SE_LOAD_DRIVER_NAME` privilege.** A process running in the system or an administrator context can elevate its privilege by using the SDK [`LookupPrivilegeValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-lookupprivilegevaluea) and [`AdjustTokenPrivileges`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-adjusttokenprivileges) functions. For more information about this see [Installing a Bluetooth Device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ff536681(v=vs.85)).

So, that means either:

- the user account that is running your app does not have that privilege at all
- your app is not enabling the privilege via `AdjustTokenPrivileges()`.

The [Installing a Bluetooth Device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ff536681(v=vs.85)) documentation provides this example of enabling the `SE_LOAD_DRIVER_NAME` privilege:

> The installation application must call the user-mode API `BluetoothSetLocalServiceInfo`. However, before the application can call this API, the application must have the `SE_LOAD_DRIVER_NAME` security privilege. The following code example demonstrates how to obtain this privilege. Note, the example does not demonstrate error handling.
>
> ```c
> HANDLE procToken;
> LUID luid;
> TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
>
> OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &procToken);
>
> LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_LOAD_DRIVER_NAME, &luid);
>
> Tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
> Tp.privileges[0].Luid = luid;
> Tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
>
> AdjustTokenPrivileges(procToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES), (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES) NULL, (PDWORD)NULL)
> ```

See [Changing Privileges in a Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secbp/changing-privileges-in-a-token) and [Enabling and Disabling Privileges in C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/enabling-and-disabling-privileges-in-c--) on MSDN for more details.

Comment: that's really easy to miss when you are new in that. I have to be more careful. Great! thank you! That solved everything!